# What is the correct import statement to use for a Select object in webdriver 2.4 under python?

Tags: python, testing, selenium, webdriver

I am writing tests with selenium webdriver 2.4 on python 2.7.

The documentation (http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) demonstrates the ability to manipulate select form elements as follows:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("Edam");
```

I need to manipulate select form elements like this but in python.  However I cannot figure out what to import to successfully instantiate the Select object.

What should my import statement be?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not python. Are you sure you're reading the right documentation?

Answer (score 1):

> However I cannot figure out what to import to successfully instantiate the Select object.

It is available as:
`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select`

See also: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select

Answer (score 0):

Since I posted this question I've spent a good amount of time searching for the python equivalent to the java Select() object and found nothing.

I've come up with a work around based on this: https://gist.github.com/1205069

Perhaps the following code will help someone save some time.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
def select_by_text(web_element, select_text):
    """given a web element representing a select object, click the option 
    matching select_text
    """
    option_is_found = False
    options = web_element.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
    for option in options:
        if option.text.strip() == select_text:
            option.click()
            option_is_found = True
            break

    if option_is_found == False:
        raise NoSuchElementException('could not find the requested element')

# ...omitted setting up the driver and getting the page 
web_element = webdriver.find_element_by_name('country_select')
select_by_text(web_element, 'Canada')
```

This code should click on the select element given its text or raise a NoSuchElementException exception if the given element is not a select form element or the text does not exist.